# account registration confirmation by email message in asp.net core identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have been trying to set up an email confirmation service like the one presented in this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio&fbclid=IwAR1xf-C9_KkNeLtwRQv4pPcMJwFY1UiMuyYWV3JlXUGEQJbfxASptWnIHgI

```
namespace lameflix_account_v1.services
{
    public class AuthMessageSenderOptions
    {
        public string SendGridKey { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
namespace lameflix_account_v1.services
{
    public class EmailSender:IEmailSender
    {
        public EmailSender(IOptions<AuthMessageSenderOptions> optionsAccessor)
        {
            Options = optionsAccessor.Value;
        }

        public AuthMessageSenderOptions Options { get; } //set only via Secret Manager

        public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
        {
            return Execute(Options.SendGridKey, subject, message, email);
        }

        public Task Execute(string apiKey, string subject, string message, string email)
        {
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var msg = new SendGridMessage()
            {
                From = new EmailAddress("Joe@contoso.com", "Password Recovery"),
                Subject = subject,
                PlainTextContent = message,
                HtmlContent = message
            };
            msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));

            // Disable click tracking.
            // See 
            msg.SetClickTracking(false, false);

            return client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

I had difficulties with the client variable, which returns nothing, I don't know what credentials are used
and if I can use gmail

```
namespace lameflix_account_v1.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

        public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
            IEmailSender emailSender,
            ApplicationDbContext dbContext,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]            
            public string Username { get; set; }
            
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public string role { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ViewData["roles"] = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Username, Email = Input.Email };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    // no caso de colocar por standart 
                    //await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, 'Client');

                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, Input.role);

                    Perfil newP = new Perfil { username = user.UserName, email=user.Email, password = user.PasswordHash};
                    _dbContext.Perfils.Add(newP);
                    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ViewData["roles"] = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace lameflix_account_v1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);

            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env,RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            SeedRoles.Seed(roleManager);

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: give us a clue here, what 'client' variable., what 'difficulties', what do you mean 'can I use gmail' you are using SendGrid. The credentials you need are your sendgrid credentials

Comment: My cliente is sent from a register class provided by identity , the place where it says execute(api k, email, etc) tha variable would launch one in the function email sender i don t know how i will reconfigure iemail sender to launch trouhh send grid

Comment: How do i obtain the api key?

Comment: sign up here https://sendgrid.com/

Comment: Was the problem been resloved or do you still need assistance on this?